# jQuery dynamic sortables with nested sortable items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

## Dynamic Sortable

[Codepen Version](https://codepen.io/pbahr/pen/VJaRay)

### Description

---

I have a problem with a dynamic sortable list, which elements should also be sortable.
The problem is, that each element in the list is dynamic, as it will be cloned from a template div and appended to document.

### Issue

---

Currently the blocks **(.pb-row)** are sortable just as expected.
But the nested sortable for the dynamically added widgets **(.builder-row-content)** doesn`t work.

Only nested nodes in the first block will be draggable and are very buggy.
Also i can drag them outside of the row.

Nodes from additionally added Blocks are not draggable at all.

Also i receive this message in the console

*cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'*

### Code

---

Html to run the sortable:

```html
 <div class="pb-rows"> // Wrapper of all Blocks
   <div class="pb-row" name="pb-row"> // each Block
      <div class="builder-row-header">
          <span class="row-btn pb-handle fas fa-sort"></span>
           <div>Block</div>
           <span onclick="handleRemoveClick(this)" class="row-btn row-btn-right pb-remove fas fa-trash"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="pb-container">
          <div class="builder-row-content">
            // nested sortable widgets will appear here
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   // more .pb-rows will appear here
 </div>
```

Attempt for jQuery sortable list:

```js
// jQuery Sorting Lib
jQuery(".pb-rows").sortable({
  handle: ".pb-handle",
  cursor: "grabbing",
});

// jQuery Sorting Lib
jQuery(".builder-row-content").sortable({
  connectWith: '.pb-rows
  handle: ".pb-handle-widget",
  cursor: "grabbing",
});
```

Attempted solution which doesnt work:

```js
const handleAddClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
  jQuery(".builder-row-content").sortable("refresh");
};
```

### Screenshot

---

[Screenshot of implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6CE9.png)

Comment: A runnable example would be nice. As this is quite a specific problem.

Comment: ok i will setup a github repo for that :)

Comment: A https://codesandbox.io/ would probably be better as we can then run it in browser :)

Comment: I created a codepen version for it: 
https://codepen.io/pbahr/pen/VJaRay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize sortable onto dynamically added elements, so:

Wrap your sortable events in a function

```
// Sorting
function enableSort() {
  // jQuery Sorting Lib
  $(".pb-rows").sortable({
    handle: ".pb-handle",
    cursor: "grabbing"
  });

  // jQuery Sorting Lib
  $(".builder-row-content").sortable({
    handle: ".pb-handle-widget",
    cursor: "grabbing"
  });
} enableSort();
```

Then call the function in `pbCreateNode`.

```
const pbCreateNode = (type, props, html) => {
  enableSort();
  let element = document.createElement(type);
  props &&
    props.forEach(prop => {
      let key = Object.keys(prop)[0];
      let value = prop[key];
      element.setAttribute(key, value);
    });
  html && (element.innerHTML = html);
  return element;
};
```